# Files 'dragged and dropped' into solution explorer in Visual Studio Community 2022 can't be tracked in git?

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, hidden-files, solution-explorer

I wanted to try dragging and dropping files from Windows Explorer in to the Solution Explorer, and it seemed to work at first. However I realised after commiting and pushing my changes to git that I couldn't see any of the .cpp or .h files I dragged in and have no idea why.

I've noticed that these files aren't showing up the same as a source file that is added by right clicking in solution explorer and clicking Add >> New item. The files I dragged and dropped in have the plus icons:
[dragged_in_files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zB3hc.png)

But are missing the padlock symbol that I can see on files that are checked in, basically on every other file in my solution explorer:
[added_in_files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezaTu.png)

On the files I have dragged in, I don't get any Git options when I right click on them, I can't see them in Windows Explorer in the project folder. I even tried excluding the files from the project just to see what would happen, but I didn't expect that they would complete disappear and are not even visible when I enable 'Show All Files' in the Solution Explorer.

I've only used Visual Studio Community Ed. for a while now and I'd just like to know how I can rectify this or enable the files to be tracked in my repo as it doesn't seem like they exist anywhere but in the IDE only.

Comment: If you do `git status`, does it show that the files are currently untracked? Also those plus icons in your image are just showing its a C++ file

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue in Visual Studio 2022. A file that has been dragged and dropped on a project in the solution explorer is added to the untracked files in git. Untracked files will have a single plus sign icon instead of a padlock icon. Your screen shot appear to show that none of the files are version controlled. Also note that drag and drop always makes a copy of the dragged file, even when the file is an existing file in the project directory.

Comment: @TimothyG. 'git status' doesn't show the files at all, nor does 'ls' and they aren't even visible in file explorer.

Comment: @JonathanDodds My repository is here: https://github.com/lokidson/cpp-oop-exercises. You can see that solution 13 doesn't have the cpp files for some reason although all the others do.

Comment: @JonathanDodds I have been able to replicate the issue and think I know what the problem is now. The first time I dragged and dropped a file in to the solution explorer, I was dragging in a file from a destination outside of the project directory and could not see the single plus icon. The second attempt I made, I dragged a file in to the solution explorer that was in the project directory, and sure enough, it was showing as a tracked file.